# How to get out of Readonly FileSystem?

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem, 19.04, fsck, read-only

I tried many things, but by the end of the week, I will be in this situation again. I am a dual boot user (Windows 10 Pro & Ubuntu 19.04). I keep both OS up to date. Unlike Windows which is very slow but stable, this distro which is very fast but not-so-stable crashes a lot.

What I do to get out of this situation are:

- Use live Ubuntu 19.04 bootable pen drive, open Gparted and check for errors
  on sda6 and sda8. Leaving swap partition (*sda7*) alone.
- Sometimes I use these two commands from live ubuntu:

  sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda6

  sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda8

where **sda6** is my *root* partition and **sda5** is my *home* partition.

- I also did this from Grub > Recovery Mode > Root shell

> ```
>    mount -n -o remount, rw /
>    touch /forcefsck
>    shutdown -r now
> ```

All answers attempts were done after observing suggestion from *askubuntu* and *ubuntuforms.org*. Help me get through this. I have tried many things. If there are other mechanisms let me know.

**Note**: *Just to be clear, the fast boot is disabled in Window OS.*

**Some information asked by the users in comments which can help my case:**

```
pranav@Inspi5548:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for pranav: 
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="EAD20314D202E4A3" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Ba" PARTUUID="aa5a9347-3807-406c-8a85-df356eb9be93"
/dev/sda2: UUID="8A05-F7D6" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="ee306771-48e7-4deb-9c8b-a23c5f0a9dc2"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="E0E07C6CE07C4B34" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f933de5f-d72a-48c0-918c-b1915e9700f2"
/dev/sda4: UUID="D8FA2AC3FA2A9DAE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="33885b82-b903-4ee7-9d91-8192f00f2209"
/dev/sda5: UUID="B4D0303ED030095E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="2d245ea3-510c-41af-825a-4f2f1608275b"
/dev/sda6: UUID="c8e65428-6dea-4e9d-b3b0-370820a1a210" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="978bac65-22b0-429b-8bb9-36e97e0754a1"
/dev/sda8: UUID="a54711ee-4373-4a1b-8d06-d0f29aca9a6b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3f5e0e3c-1884-4597-bdf2-6496941b4fd1"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"

pranav@Inspi5548:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=c8e65428-6dea-4e9d-b3b0-370820a1a210 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
#UUID=8A05-F7D6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=a54711ee-4373-4a1b-8d06-d0f29aca9a6b /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=1ad69fff-0367-4131-b0a2-839fd5b3846f none            swap    sw              0       0
#UUID=a54711ee-4373-4a1b-8d06-d0f29aca9a6b  /boot   ext4defaults    0   2
UUID=8A05-F7D6  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1

pranav@Inspi5548:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 36
drwxrwxr-x 9 pranav pranav 4096 Aug 22 12:54 .
drwx------ 3 pranav pranav 4096 Aug 29 16:02 ..
drwxrwxr-x 5 pranav pranav 4096 Jul 29 16:39 caffeine@patapon.info
drwxrwxr-x 5 pranav pranav 4096 Aug  4 22:56 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 4 pranav pranav 4096 Jul 29 16:24 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxrwxr-x 6 pranav pranav 4096 Aug 11 15:26 gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io
drwxrwxr-x 2 pranav pranav 4096 Jul 29 21:33 Hide_Activities@shay.shayel.org
drwxrwxr-x 2 pranav pranav 4096 Aug 22 12:54 remove-alt-tab-delay@tetrafox.pw
drwxrwxr-x 4 pranav pranav 4096 Jul 29 16:46 status-area-horizontal-spacing@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com
```

[This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GECZR.jpg) from `Disks` "SMART Data & Self-Test" window, and [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9NGw.jpg) from `gparted` application. Both were taken from Live Ubuntu 19.04.

**Note**, I have used # to comment in multiple places in `/etc/fstab` to resolve the issue, and this is the output after that event.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="EAD20314D202E4A3" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Ba" PARTUUID="aa5a9347-3807-406c-8a85-df356eb9be93"
/dev/sda2: UUID="8A05-F7D6" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="ee306771-48e7-4deb-9c8b-a23c5f0a9dc2"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="E0E07C6CE07C4B34" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f933de5f-d72a-48c0-918c-b1915e9700f2"
/dev/sda4: UUID="D8FA2AC3FA2A9DAE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="33885b82-b903-4ee7-9d91-8192f00f2209"
/dev/sda5: UUID="B4D0303ED030095E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="2d245ea3-510c-41af-825a-4f2f1608275b"
/dev/sda6: UUID="c8e65428-6dea-4e9d-b3b0-370820a1a210" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="978bac65-22b0-429b-8bb9-36e97e0754a1"
/dev/sda8: UUID="a54711ee-4373-4a1b-8d06-d0f29aca9a6b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3f5e0e3c-1884-4597-bdf2-6496941b4fd1"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="UBUNTU 19_0" UUID="15E4-2844" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Microsoft Basic Data" PARTUUID="5c3b9d59-eab7-47c5-85c0-55654f42445a"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: While i did not have dual boot, i got the `read-only filesystem` quite frecuentely. In my case for some reason it got resolved by installing a newer kernel. The other option that i evaluated at the time was a faulty hdd, which may get the system into `readonly mode` to avoid data looses.

Comment: @bistoco As a temporary solution, I did this," UUID=c8e65428-6dea-4e9d-b3b0-370820a1a210 /     ext4    errors=remount-rw 0      1" in /etc/fstab. 
But I want a more permanent solution.

Comment: If you don't identify the reason why it gets into `readonly mode`, you are risking data loss. Try upgrading you system and run a health scan on the hdd. Also you may get info on `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: @bistoco what do u mean by "health scan"? Is there such command? Yes my OS is always updated. It is updated. I don't think there is any there is any update available. And I am lock out, I can copy the /var/log/syslog to show u. So...

Comment: Edit your question with two screenshots of: open the `Disks` app, select the HDD, select `SMART Data & Tests` from the "hamburger" icon. View the Data window, take a screenshot, scroll the window, take a second screenshot. Then run the SMART Tests. Report back.

Comment: Have you installed a driver in Windows which allows you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions?

Comment: @heynnema no, I don't think I done something that would read/write to Linux from Windows. (Update: After 12 hours, I can use Ubuntu again, but I wonder how long it gonna last. Unless I never shutdown)

Comment: @bistoco this is what inside my /var/log/syslog: https://pastebin.com/6KSJz6k8

Comment: I don't see the `Disks` screenshots.

Comment: Also, edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Do you have calibre-viewer set up as a startup application?

Comment: @heynnema I want to use "Disk application" and scanning for the last 4 hours but due to load-shedding, I can't keep it up. I add some information u asked.

Comment: @heynnema I added more details. Making the question very big, I hope it's not against 'askubuntu rules'.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment " scanning for the last 4 hours but due to load-shedding". The information that I requested from the `Disks` app doesn't require any scanning. I was looking for the SMART Data window screenshots.

Comment: @heynnema so sorry, I miss interpretated your points. So I start scanning the disk, which lasted for 4 hours, and "electricity" went out and my Laptop can't survive more than 5 minutes, so I have cancel the scanning at 90%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more than one problem here.

First, your swap partition is missing. `/etc/fstab` shows:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=1ad69fff-0367-4131-b0a2-839fd5b3846f none            swap    sw              0       0
```

The system is trying to mount the swap partition, and not finding it. Did you delete `/dev/sda7`, or change to a `/swapfile`?

Second, you may have a GNOME extension problem. I see multiple extensions that may be causing problems. You'll want to temporarily disable ALL extensions, run the computer for a while, and see if some of the problems go away. Then re-enable one at a time, and see if problems return. Possible suspects are `Dash to Dock`, `GS Connect`, and `Status Area Horiz Spacing`. See https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ to disable/enable them.

**Update #1:**

Your problem is with `/dev/sda7`, the swap partition, and that's why you're having problems.

So first, lets edit `/etc/fstab` and change this:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=1ad69fff-0367-4131-b0a2-839fd5b3846f none            swap    sw              0       0
```

to this:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
# UUID=1ad69fff-0367-4131-b0a2-839fd5b3846f none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Then you should probably be able to boot. We'll start to fix `/dev/sda7` with the next Update.

In the `terminal`, type:

```
reboot
```

**Update #2:**

In the `terminal` type:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Then we'll bad block `/dev/sda7`. This may fail, due to the nature of the failure in `/dev/sda7`. If it does work, we'll still have to recreate this partition, and then edit `/etc/fstab`.

```
Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours
```

<strike>Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.</strike>

In `terminal`...

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sda7` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda7` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.

   -y     Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
          used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
          same time as the -n or -p options.
```

**Update #3:**

**Note: you may have a failing HDD...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda6`
  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda8`
- boot to the HDD, even if it's in emergency mode
- do Update #1 again
- also remove the extra mounts that you've added to /etc/fstab
- using `gparted`, swapoff /dev/sda7, delete /dev/sda7, and create a new **ext4** partition on /dev/sda7
- `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda7`
- `sudo blkid` should now show /dev/sda7, if **not**, then **STOP**, and consult with me
- do Update #2 again, but this way...

  - boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
  - `sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda7`
  - `sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda6`
  - `sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda8`
- using `gparted`, delete the **ext4** partition /dev/sda7, and create a new **linux-swap** partition at /dev/sda7, and swapon /dev/sda7... if this step **fails**, then **STOP**, and consult with me
- `reboot`
- `sudo blkid | grep swap` and get the new UUID and edit that into /etc/fstab, also uncomment that same line
- `reboot`

**Update #4:**

All the work has been done, and the system is running right now... however, the HDD is failing, and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98153/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-how-to-get-out-of-readonly-filesystem).

Comment: @heynnema for now everything looks fine. Thanks to u. The sad thing is it took 7 days. After a long discussion, we made it. P.S: I should have chosen LTS instead of non-LTS.

Comment: @Prabeshbhattarai Great news! LTS vs non-LTS woulnd't have made any difference, as your problem was with your hard disk. When you bad blocked the three partitions, did it report any bad blocks?

Comment: @Prabeshbhattarai I saw your last comment in the chat log, and I've reviewed the logs you posted. Everything went well... except that your HDD is failing. Backup whatever data is important to you, and replace your HDD asap.

Comment: @Prabeshbhattarai I read your last comments in chat. The problem isn't Ubuntu. The problem is that your HDD is failing. Backup your important files and replace it.

Comment: @heynnema Really! We will see that. If I see same error messages in Debian than u r right. If not, u r wrong. I will let u know after two weeks or a month. Until then, TC

Comment: @Prabeshbhattarai If you review your SMART Data window, you'll see that the error rates are very high. Also, when you bad blocked your Ubuntu partitions, you had contiguous bad blocks, indicating a large scratch on the surface of your hard disk (indicating a possible head crash). If Debian is on different partitions, you may not see an error, as they're different than your Ubuntu partitions. And... I'm never wrong... :-)